# How to collect cumulative report for 32 repos?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, python, jenkinsfile, shell-script

We use separate Jenkins jobs to collect unit tests and coverage for each repository. There are 32 such repos. How do we collect cumulative report?

Currently we are going into each job and collecting the report manually for each repository. Typically it takes 90 minutes to complete this process as we maintain in a table or an Excel and send it to team. We need to automate this to save our efforts.